# NerdDinner DinnerFormViewModel Error CS0030 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am following the NerdDinner part in the Book Professional ASP.NET MVC 2. Currently i am at the part where i need to implement the DinnerFormViewModel and the Renderpartial Dinnerform.
The book contains some errors here so I tried to search on the internet and fix it myself..

I have put the DinnerFormViewModel in the Models folder this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    public class DinnerFormViewModel : Controller
    {
        private static string[] _countries = new[]{
        "USA",
        "Ireland",
        "Scotland",
        "Namibia"
    };

        //Properties
        public Dinner Dinner { get; private set; }
        public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

        //Constructor
        public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner)
        {
            Dinner = dinner;
            Countries = new SelectList(_countries, dinner.Country);
        }


        // GET: /DinnerFormViewModel/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Then i have made the DinnerForm.ascx (Partial class):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel>" %>


<%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <fieldset>

        <p>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dinner.Title) %>
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dinner.Title) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Dinner.Title, "*") %>
```

ETC...

and i have made the edit.aspx as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit: <%: Model.Dinner.Title %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Edit" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Edit Dinner</h2>

    <% Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm"); %>

</asp:Content>
```

Now if i start the application, an error at <% Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm"); %> will popup saying:
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c8cca855\23406a1e\App_Web_dinnerform.ascx.32d6c807.tczxq3bd.0.cs(166): error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ASP.views_dinners_dinnerform_ascx' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'

I think it has something to do with the namespaces, but i can't fix the error, someone faced the same problem or someone here that can help me out?? Thank you!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your partial view should inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl.

ViewPage is for a full view.

Comment: hehe your right, i tried it on the edit.aspx but it needed to go on the dinnerform.ascx, thnx!